# Solr: Combine multiple queries together with OR relation

Tags: solr, lucene

I need to filter on the same field with multiple possibilities with and OR relation.

I have a station with 2 points that have status of 'FREE', 'IN_USE', 'ERROR' or 'UNKNOWN' in a field.

```
Field
<field name="point_statusses" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />

SQL
GROUP_CONCAT(cp.status) as point_statusses
```

I can filter on one thing using this method

```
/select?=q=*:*&fq={!frange l=1 u=2}termfreq(point_statusses,'FREE')
```

but i can't get for example all the stations with 1 or 2 FREE points and those that have 2 IN_USE points.

Hope that someone can help :-)

Comment: Please, try to specify a little bit more information about the issue itself in the future (e.g. if there's some error or it just silently fails to work as expected, what is the error message, etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using [Nested Queries](http://searchhub.org/2009/03/31/nested-queries-in-solr/):

```
_query_:"{!frange l=1 u=2}termfreq(point_statusses,'FREE')" OR _query_:"{!frange l=2 u=2}termfreq(point_statusses,'IN_USE')"
```

Comment: Thanks man! I knew this was possible but couldn't find it because i was searching on multiple queries ;)